# POST Ajax call show parameters on HTTP address

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application in which i create an Ajax call (with POST) that i use to set a password.

After i set the password (and the call return success response) the url of application show the value of the password parameter. I want to hide the parameter on web address.

How i can do that?

Here is the code

**Javascript Ajax call**

```
 $.ajax({
        url: ApplicationParams.cambiaPassword,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: { 'context': ApplicationParams.ctx,  'userId': userId,'nuovaPassword':nuovaPwd },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            if (result.Success) {                    
                ShowSuccessMessage(scopeAdz, result.Message);                    
            } else {                                       
                ShowErrorMessage(scopeAdz, data.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            alert("c'è stato un'errore");
        }
    });
```

**View code**

```
<div id="modalFooterNuovoCliente" class="modal-footer">
<div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-success"onclick="cambiaPassword(@Model.AnagraficaUser.Data.U_id)" id="btnCambiaPassword">Conferma</button>
 </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult CambiaPassword(string context,int userId, string nuovaPassword)
    {
        Logger.Debug("CambiaPassword");
        BaseResult<bool> resuCheck = new BaseResult<bool>();

        using (IContext ctx = ServiceLocator.Instance.GetContext(context))
        {
            var service = ServiceLocator.Instance.GetService<ILogin>(ctx);
            resuCheck = service.CambiaPassword(context, userId, nuovaPassword);                
            return Json(resuCheck);
        }
    }
```

**Web address after ajax call**

```
http://localhost:55196/WOfficine/GestioneAnagrafica/IR/PAJjVjhGsfqg3vKkWn8p?password=ChangeMe!
```